# How to add all values from UnmodifiableSet to ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, set, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a twinColSelect and i m populating this from database. I need to access its selected items. I tried below the code but it didn't worked. How can i do that ?

```
ArrayList<String> systemNames = new ArrayList<String>();
systemNames = (ArrayList<String>) twinColSelectSystem.getValue();

for (int i=0;i<systemNames.size();i++)
System.out.println(systemNames.get(i));
```

Comment: TwinColSelect returns java.util.Set

Comment: is there a way to add components to ArrayList ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ArrayList<String> systemNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    systemNames.addAll((Set<String>) twinColSelectSystem.getValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> systemNames =
    new ArrayList<String>((Set<String>) twinColSelectSystem.getValue());
```

Comment: Throwable occurred: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet incompatible with java.util.ArrayList